# WP7 Mango - navigation inside buildings

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I'm currently working on a app that should be able to navigate you inside a building - the basic idea is to have the building schematics, floor by floor and on every floor it tells you where to go to get to the next one. Once you are on the next floor, you press a button and its schema appears.

While this works fine, I came across and idea to automatize it - use the buildings WiFi access points, meassure the strength of the signal and triangulate your position. However, I read that in WP7 there is no way to access available WiFi networks. Does it still apply in Mango? Or is there some workaround?

Or any other idea how to automatize navigation inside building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for WiFi (neither with Mango), and as such, you can't triangulate any positions from it.

And there's no workaround.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thx for the answer